# what does it mean by $\| A \|$ for a matrix $A$ here?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand notation which I can not find the explanation for in the book...
It says:
Since
$$
(f_1(\mathbf{x}), \ldots, f_n(\mathbf{x})) = A (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0) + O(|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0  |^2)
$$
we have
$$
|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0| \leq \| A^{-1} \| (|(f_1(\mathbf{x}), \ldots, f_n(\mathbf{x}))| + C|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0  |^2 ).  
$$
Here $A$ is an invertible real matrix, $|\cdot |$ denotes $L^2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{x}_0$ is a fixed vector.
What exactly does $\| A^{-1}\|$ mean in this context? Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: To @JohnnyT: What book you are reading?

Comment: Context matters here, surely the reference defines the notation it uses.  There are several "natural" [norms on matrix spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394113/what-are-some-usual-norms-for-matrices).  Given the use of the $L^2$  on $\mathbb R^n$, perhaps they mean something like that on matrix spaces but, as I say, the book will state, somewhere, exactly what they mean.

Comment: It is Hormander: The analysis of linear partial differential opeators I. I just can not find the definition...

Comment: Most  likely  $\| A^{-1}\|$ denotes the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @jd27 When you hover over the "Add comment" button, it displays a tooltip. "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the induced (operator or 2 norm) norm arising from the $L^2$ norm on vectors,

$\left| B \right|=\underset{\left| x \right|=1}{\mathop{\sup }}\,\left| Bx \right|$

It can be found explicitly as the square root of the largest eigenvalue of of $B^TB$   if B is a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that Hörmander has defined which matrix norm $\lVert B \rVert$ he uses in his book.

But certainly any matrix norm satisfying
$$\lvert B \cdot \mathbf x \rvert \le \lVert B \rVert \cdot \lvert \mathbf x \rvert \tag{1}$$
gives the desired result. Condition $(1)$ says that the matrix norm $\lVert - \rVert$ is *consistent* with the vector norm $\lvert - \rvert$.

Given any vector norm, the operatornorm
$$\lVert B \rVert = \sup \left\{ \frac{\lvert B \cdot \mathbf x \vert}{\lvert  \mathbf x \vert} \mid \mathbf x \ne 0 \right\}$$
always has this property.

However, there are many other examples of consistent matrix and vector norms. I guess that Hörmander uses the Euclidean norm (aka Frobenius norm)
$$\lVert B \rVert  = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} b_{ij}^2} .$$

This norm is  submultiplicative which means that
$$\lVert B \cdot C \rVert  \le \lVert B \rVert  \cdot \lVert C \rVert. $$
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351981).

Taking any matrix norm, we can define an associated vector norm by
$$\lvert \mathbf x \rvert_{ass} = \left \lVert M(\mathbf x,n)  \right \rVert .$$
Here we regard $\mathbf x$ as a column vector and form the matrix $M(\mathbf x,n)$ having $\mathbf x$ in all $n$ columns.

If the matrix norm is submultplicative, then it is clearly consistent with its associated vector norm.

Working with the Euclidean matrix norm gives
$$\lvert \mathbf x \rvert_{ass} = \sqrt n \lvert \mathbf x \rvert .$$ Therfore
$$\lvert B \cdot \mathbf x \rvert = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \lvert B \cdot \mathbf x \rvert_{ass} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \lVert B \rVert \cdot \lvert x \rvert_{ass} = \lVert B \rVert \cdot \lvert x \rvert .$$